# Python: Write a list to a column in Pandas

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas

I have two lists that both contain values that I want to write into a csv file. So the first thing I did is to import my csv file to pandas dataframe. Then I want to write two new columns and add those two lists to the new columns. My code is as below. Please note that the original csv file already has a few columns existed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')  ## 1.csv is the csv file I want to import. 


a = [0.001, 5, 38, 70, 101, 140, 190]

b= [35, 65,  100, 160, 170, 200]

df['Start Time'] = a
df['End Time'] = b 

df.to_csv('1.csv')
```

However, when I run this code, it gave me an error as below,

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: I'm counting 7 values in a and 6 values in b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need create `Series` first, but get `NaN`s for all last values in `df` if length is not same as length of `DataFrame`:

```
df['Start Time'] = pd.Series(a, index = df.index[:len(a)])
df['End Time'] = pd.Series(b, index = df.index[:len(b)])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})

a = [0.001, 9, 46, 84, 122, 153, 198]
b= [39, 76,  114, 150, 158, 210]

df['Start Time'] = pd.Series(a, index = df.index[:len(a)])
df['End Time'] = pd.Series(b, index = df.index[:len(b)]) 
print (df)
   a  Start Time  End Time
0  0       0.001      39.0
1  1       9.000      76.0
2  2      46.000     114.0
3  3      84.000     150.0
4  4     122.000     158.0
5  5     153.000     210.0
6  6     198.000       NaN
7  7         NaN       NaN
8  8         NaN       NaN
9  9         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I tried this and it indeed works. But it also gave the csv file 2 new "unnamed" columns which I think is their indices. Would you pls share how to add it without writing the index to the file too? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need `df.to_csv('new.csv', index=False)` ?

Comment: I see and yes it works! One last issue is that I also have some blank column in my csv file. However when I ran this, it gave the first row of those columns an 'unnamed' word. Could you pls share how to do so this won't happen? Thanks!!

Comment: So if use `print (df.columns.tolist())`  get unnamed columns names?

Comment: It gave me an error " tolist() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" when I typed 'unnamed' to the parenthesis?  Also sorry that I want to mention a previous question too. I do want to get rid of those indices but I want to keep just one left. Is there any way to do it? All I can think is to do an enumerate method again but is there any simpler way?

Comment: Sorry, but it is really hard answer for it, because I have no data. Can you  create new one question? The best is create small data sample - 3 rows, 5 columns dataframe and explain what is problem with unnamed columns. I have to go away, but i think get nice answers too. But if really want to help with me, is possible send me some data sample to my email (in my profile) and tomorrow I try find solution for you. But if need solution faster, try new question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!! So my questions is simple:  1. Is there any way to get rid of the 'unnamed' word in my blank columns? 2. I want to keep one index left instead of deleting all indices using the `index=False`. Pls let me know if you know how to solve it thanks!!

Comment: 1. maybe help `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('unnamed','')` and for second need `df.reset_index(level=0).to_csv('new.csv', index=False)` or `df.reset_index(level=1).to_csv('new.csv', index=False)` - it depends which level can be removed.

Comment: 1. it still doesn't remove it.. Because now I found those 'unnamed' words are given with numbers by the columns like unnamed:0 & unnamed: 4. I think it is because the `.Series` gives the blank column in the first row to 'unnamed'. Is there a way to just remove it or replace it?

Comment: 2. It gave me an error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable?

Comment: Never mind! I solved it thanks! :)   Turned out the 'unnamed' issue happens because I wrote the original file from another code files, and when I combine these two codes together and the problem will not happen. Also the second problem is no longer an issue when I combine these two codes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also try out changing the datatypes of a and b into strings. In that way the NAN values will be left blank.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')  ## 1.csv is the csv file I want to import. 


a = [0.001, 5, 38, 70, 101, 140, 190]

b = [35, 65,  100, 160, 170, 200]

df['Start Time'] = str(a)
df['End Time'] = str(b) 

df.to_csv('1.csv')
```